# Optimizing django related set average in a django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, postgresql, caching, optimization, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.8 with Django Rest Framework.
I have two models: `Marker` and `MarkerComment`.

```
class Marker(models.Model):
    # a bunch of fields here...

    def rating(self):
        """
        Return the mean rating from all comments
        """
        return self.comments.aggregate(models.Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']


class MarkerComment(models.Model):
    # a few fields here...

    marker = models.ForeignKey(Marker, blank=False, related_name='comments')    
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False)
```

In my serializer I have something like this :

```
class MarkerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Marker
        fields = (
            'url', 'pk', 'created', 'name', 'category', 'rating', ...
        )
        read_only_fields = ('rating')
```

The `list` query on my serializer is taking way too long since it's querying every single marker to get the average. See NewRelic:

[image: New Relic graph, it's very slow]
[image: 1,800ms average]

This is the query that's run for every marker in my result set:

```
SELECT AVG("maps_markercomment"."rating") AS "rating__avg" FROM "maps_markercomment" WHERE "maps_markercomment"."marker_id" = 1788
```

If I wasn't using Django Rest Framework, I'd probably do something to get all the ratings at once like

```
Marker.objects.filter(...).annotate(rating=Avg('comments__rating'))
```

So my question is: what are my options here to make it faster? Is there a way to have all this in a single SQL query while still using the serializer? How do I have to cache the rating for every marker?

Comment: Can you not apply your desired optimization to the queryset in the view?

Comment: Duh... you're right... I had all the elements in place ;) I just added at the end of my `get_queryset(self)` method in the ViewSet: `return queryset.annotate(rating=Avg('comments__rating'))` instead of `return queryset` and everything is fast!

Comment: Feel free to add your response as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Also add a `prefetch_related('comments')` to your query. It could help even more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply your desired optimizations to the queryset in your view(s), as this optimized queryset will ultimately be passed to the serializers.